# Suma de inputs Checkbox y Text Tiempo real

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Necesito sumar el input tipo text con los input tipo checkbox, en este momento al hacer click en los checkbox me va sumando y mostrando el total, pero necesito que me sume tambien el input tipo text llamado precio servicio.

Esta es una captura de pantalla de mi formulario:

[image: Mi Formulario]

Este es mi código:

```
<?php foreach($servicelist as $listsv): ?>
<input name="service[]" type="checkbox" onClick="if (this.checked) sumar(<?php echo $listsv["price"]; ?>); else restar(<?php echo $listsv["price"]; ?>)" value='<?php echo $listsv["id"]; ?>'><?php echo utf8_encode($listsv['service']); ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<br>
```

Esta es mi función

```
var total = 0;

function sumar(valor) {
    total += valor;
    document.formulario.total.value = '$' + total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

function restar(valor) {
    total -= valor;
    document.formulario.total.value = '$' + total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

function otro_servicio() {
    $("#lineas").append('<label>Nombre Servicio</label>');
    $("#lineas").append('<input name="othersv" type="text" class="form-control importe_linea" placeholder="Nombre del servicio extra"/><br/>');
    $("#lineas").append('<label>Precio Servicio</label>');
    $("#lineas").append('<input name="price" type="text" class="form-control importe_linea" placeholder="Precio del servicio"/><br/>');
}
```

Para lograr este objetivo puedo usar javascript, jquery o angular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podrías guardar el precio de los elementos **checkbox** como un atributo de estos elementos y luego añadir un **listener** al clic de los checkbox y al keyup del input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(document).on('click keyup','.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales',function() {
   calcular();
 });

});

function calcular() {
  var tot = $('#total');
  tot.val(0);
  $('.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('mis-checkboxes')) {
      tot.val(($(this).is(':checked') ? parseFloat($(this).attr('tu-attr-precio')) : 0) + parseFloat(tot.val()));  
    }
    else {
      tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val())));
    }
  });
  var totalParts = parseFloat(tot.val()).toFixed(2).split('.');
  tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' +  (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00'));  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="3.5" class="mis-checkboxes" /> Elemento #1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="7.5" class="mis-checkboxes" /> Elemento #2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="5.5" class="mis-checkboxes" /> Elemento #3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="4.5" class="mis-checkboxes" /> Elemento #4</li>
</ul>

<label><strong>Servicio adicional</strong><label>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="mis-adicionales" placeholder="Precio del servicio"/>
</div>

<label><strong>Total</strong><label>
<div>
  <input id="total" type="text" placeholder="0.00"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Javier muchas gracias! exactamente lo que necesitaba, bendiciones

Comment: Fue un placer haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola javier otra consulta referente a mi problema anterior, lo que pasa es que el valor o dato a enviar es el ID del input tipo checkbox en mi caso el id del servicio, entonces cuando preciono o selecciono los checkbox me suma son los id, alguna manera de que me sume el valor?? es que en el value estan los id y no el precio el precio lo ponia en el onclick

Comment: en otras palabras hacer que sume no el valor del value=del input tipo checkbox, si no que lo tome de otro lado? onclick? o algo, muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes utilizar un atributo específico y colocar el valor en ese atributo. Haré el cambio en el código. Recuerda darle clic al up vote de mi respuesta (icono de triangulo hacia arriba al inicio de mi respuesta)

Comment: Hola javier, a la espera del cambio de codigo, y si ya lo vote :)

Comment: modificado. Puedes revisarlo

Comment: como podria hacer que el total se visualizara como antes lo tenia? ejemplo: value='$'+total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

Comment: Cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: hola quiero que en el input que muestra el total del valor se conviertan a precio por ejemplo que se muestre asi $104,850 .....los datos de la base de datos vienen asi 104850 y quiero que se vean en ese input de esta manera $104,850, que pena molestar tanto

Comment: El valor del input total viajara al servidor y debe guardarse en la base de datos? Si intentas guardar el valor con la coma en la base de datos, seguro te arrojará error. Antes de insertarlo, deberás quitar el separador de miles.

Comment: hola, el valor no se guardara, solamente se visualizara en el input de dicha manera, el registro en la db lo guardare como entero.

Comment: modificado. Revisalo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una función Jquery/javascript como esta.

```
function Sumar() {
    var div = $('#RegistroServicio');
    var divSumar = $(div).find('[name$="price"]');
    var Total = 0;
    var temp = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < divSumar.length; i++) {

        var Monto = parseFloat(divSumar[i].value).toFixed(2);
        if (Monto === 'NaN') {
            Monto = 0;
        }
        Total = parseFloat(parseFloat(Total) + parseFloat(Monto)).toFixed(2);

    }
    $('#suma').val(Total);
}
```

La función la puedes agregar en el evento onclick de todos los inputs de precio

```
$("#lineas").append('<input name="price" type="text" class="form-control importe_linea" placeholder="Precio del servicio" onclick="Sumar()"/><br/>');
```

Y el input de Precio de servicio puede tomar el resultado del total

```
<label>Precio del servicio</label>
<input id="suma" name="Total" type="text" value="0" />
```

Espero y te sirva :)

Comment: hola amigo no me sirvio tu codigo, aun asi muchas gracias por su respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas usar javascript, esta puede ser una opción:

Lo que hace el siguiente código se describe de esta manera:

Cada vez que el estado del `CheckBox` cambie, verificará el valor de la suma que exista en el momento y *si está chequeado*, sumará el valor del check a la suma general, de lo contrario, resta ese valor del check.

Este es el código:

```js
function actualizarValor(estaChequeado, valor) {

  // Variables.
  var suma_actual = 0;
  var campo_resultado = document.getElementById('txtValor');
  valor = parseInt(valor);

  // Obtener la suma que pueda tener el campo 'txtValor'.
  try {
    if (campo_resultado != null) {

      if (isNaN(campo_resultado.value)) {
        campo_resultado.value = 0;
      }

      suma_actual = parseInt(campo_resultado.value);
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    alert('No existe el campo de la suma.');
  }

  // Determinar que: si el check está seleccionado "checked"
  // entonces, agregue el valor a la variable "suma_actual";
  // de lo contrario, le resta el valor del check a "suma_actual".
  if (estaChequeado == true) {
    suma_actual = suma_actual + valor;
  } else {
    suma_actual = suma_actual - valor;
  }

  // Colocar el resultado de las operaciones anteriores de vuelta
  // al campo "txtValor".
  campo_resultado.value = suma_actual;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" value="1" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);" /> <span>CheckBox #1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_2" value="2" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);" /> <span>CheckBox #2</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_3" value="3" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);" /> <span>CheckBox #3</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk_4" value="4" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);" /> <span>CheckBox #4</span>
</div>

<div>
  <i>El resultado es </i><input type="text" readonly id="txtValor" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, esa parte la tengo ya hecha amigo, pero me pregunto es que bueno yo seleciono unos checkbox, y quiero que se sume el valor que yo ponga en el input type text, muchas gracias

Comment: @Wilson. puedes entonces quitar la propiedad `readonly` del input que tengo en mi ejemplo.